# How to put a condition for Oracle statement in a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Why i cannot put the condition like this in the trigger?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HDR_WEB_UPD
BEFORE UPDATE ON  HDR_WEB_LATEST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.UPD_USR = 'MARS72' OR :NEW.UPD_USR ='ROHA' OR :NEW.UPD_USR ='TAJUL'
   THEN
          IF :NEW.STATUS = 2
          THEN
                 IF :OLD.STATUS = 2 AND :NEW.VER_USR := :OLD.VER_USR
                  THEN
                  :NEW.status := :OLD.status;
                  :NEW.VER_DATE := :OLD.VER_DATE;
                  :NEW.VER_USR := :OLD.VER_USR;

                 ELSE
                 :NEW.VER_DATE := SYSDATE;
                 :NEW.VER_USR := :NEW.UPD_USR;

          END IF;
   END IF;
   else
                    :NEW.UPD_USR := :OLD.UPD_USR;
                    :NEW.VER_DATE := :OLD.VER_DATE;
                    :NEW.VER_USR := :OLD.VER_USR;
                    :NEW.closed_date := :OLD.closed_date;
                    :NEW.CLOSE_USR := :OLD.CLOSE_USR;
                    :NEW.status := :OLD.status;
   END IF;
END;
```

The error found is

> Error(8,47): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one
>   of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder
>   not rem then     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
>   like2    like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset
>   The symbol "* was inserted before "=" to continue.

Comment: `:NEW.VER_USR := :OLD.VER_USR`?  I guess you mean: `:NEW.VER_USR = :OLD.VER_USR` (comparison vs assignment). (And some consistent indentation would not harm either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions needs to evaluate to true, false or null. In order to do that, you will have to use one of the comparison operators: =, <, >, <=, >=, <>, !=, ~=, ^=, IS NULL, LIKE, BETWEEN, IN.

The issue appears to be on line and the corrected line is `IF :OLD.STATUS = 2 AND :NEW.VER_USR = :OLD.VER_USR`. The modified trigger is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HDR_WEB_UPD
BEFORE UPDATE ON  HDR_WEB_LATEST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.UPD_USR = 'MARS72' OR :NEW.UPD_USR ='ROHA' OR :NEW.UPD_USR ='TAJUL'
    THEN
            IF :NEW.STATUS = 2
            THEN
                    IF :OLD.STATUS = 2 AND :NEW.VER_USR = :OLD.VER_USR
                    THEN
                        :NEW.status := :OLD.status;
                        :NEW.VER_DATE := :OLD.VER_DATE;
                        :NEW.VER_USR := :OLD.VER_USR;
                    ELSE
                        :NEW.VER_DATE := SYSDATE;
                        :NEW.VER_USR := :NEW.UPD_USR;
                END IF;
        END IF;
    ELSE
                :NEW.UPD_USR := :OLD.UPD_USR;
                :NEW.VER_DATE := :OLD.VER_DATE;
                :NEW.VER_USR := :OLD.VER_USR;
                :NEW.closed_date := :OLD.closed_date;
                :NEW.CLOSE_USR := :OLD.CLOSE_USR;
                :NEW.status := :OLD.status;
    END IF;
END;
```